# How to divide the data in groups at regular intervals by referring to the value of the series

Tags: python, pandas

There is **1 Dataframe** and **1 series**

A dataframe (***df1***) consists of a model and its Lots

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'model':['A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C','C'],
            'lot':['a1','a2','a3','a4','a5','b1','b2','b3','b4','c1','c2','c3','c4','c5']})
```

[image]

A Series(***s1***) has information about the volume of each model's box.

```
s1 = pd.Series({'A':3, 'B':2,'C':4}, name='box_volume')
```

[image]

For example, ***model A*** has 5 lots, but since there are only three volumes in box A, you have to fill ***box_1 and then box_2***

If the model changes, you have to change the box again. So in the case of **Model B**, there are 4 lots, and the maximum number of boxes is two, so there are ***box_3 and box_4.***

The same rule of the ***model C*** dong fills **box_5 with four, and then the box_6** is filled with one.

The picture below is what I want

[image]

Comment: there is no `c3, c4, c5` in initial df

Comment: would the last box_1 be box_6?

Comment: sorry. there are some mistakes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work

```
(df1.groupby(['model',
df1.groupby('model').cumcount().floordiv(df1['model'].map(s1))])
.ngroup()
.add(1)
.astype('str')
.radd('box_'))
```

Output:

```
0     box_1
1     box_1
2     box_1
3     box_2
4     box_2
5     box_3
6     box_3
7     box_4
8     box_4
9     box_5
10    box_5
11    box_5
12    box_5
13    box_6
```

Comment: Except the output is not the same as OP (and I think you are right), the solution is really clever. +1

Comment: there are my mistakes, but you recognizing my righteousness. thank you.